# ndk-build Error prebuilt-library.mk:28: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, .a

I'm getting the error

```
 Android NDK: ERROR:src/main/jni/Android.mk:Cortex: The LOCAL_SRC_FILES
 for a prebuilt library should only contain one item
 /Users/peterchappy/Library/Android/ndk/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:28:
 *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

when I run ndk-build. I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# static library info
LOCAL_MODULE := Cortex
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := CortexLibrary-i386
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# wrapper info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../prebuild/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := wrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrapper.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libYourLibrary
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static 
APP_PLATFORM := android-8 
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yourmodule.a
```

before:

```
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

inside prebuilt-library.mk you can see:

```
# Check that LOCAL_SRC_FILES contains only paths to shared libraries
ifneq ($(words $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)),1)
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt static library should only contain one item))
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
endif
```

or maybe it is set to some invalid value and you rather should add:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

right after:

```
# static library info
```

Answer (score 0):

I add ndk abiFilters at my build.gradle,and it works.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.coffee.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```